# How do I approach this combinatorics problem involving labeled and unlabelled configurations

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Here is the question:

> If we allow  *f(n)* and *g(n)* to represent the number of labeled and
>   unlabelled configurations, respectively, of *n* objects, then why is
>   the following reasonable?  You  should include your assumptions 
>   (e.g., how you understand the  terms “labeled” and “unlabelled”).
>   *f(n)/n! ≤ g(n) ≤ f(n)*

I appreciate any tips or advice.

Comment: Given any unlabeled configuration using $n$ objects, there are $n!$ ways to apply labels to the individual objects.

Comment: @AustinMohr - Thanks a lot, Cool yes that is a big hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take an unlabeled configuration, in how many ways can you apply labels to the objects? What happens if these are all identical? What happens if they're all distinct?

Comment: Thank You Very Much Joriki, I have a clearer picture now.